# display list of pdf and image separately from api in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, pdf, flutter-layout

I want to display a list of images and pdf files that I am getting from API in response by separating them into PFD and image.
I have successfully displayed an images list that I am getting from API in circleAvatar using image.network, but now I am not getting the idea of how do I display a pdf list so that when I tap one pdf it opens in a viewer.
below is the image of how I want to display it in the list -:
[image]

the first blue circle is empty because it has a pdf path and the next has an image.

code for displaying the image and pdf file -

```
GridView.count(
                                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                                children: List.generate(document?.length, (ind) {
                                                  return
                                                        Padding(
                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                          child: CircleAvatar(
                                                            radius: 80,
                                                            backgroundImage:
                                                            NetworkImage('${api.getHTTPUri('/${document[ind].documentPath}')}'),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                }),
                                              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following package from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) : `flutter_pdfview`

```
PDFView(
  filePath: path,
  enableSwipe: true,
  swipeHorizontal: true,
  autoSpacing: false,
  pageFling: false,
  onRender: (_pages) {
    setState(() {
      pages = _pages;
      isReady = true;
    });
  },
  onError: (error) {
    print(error.toString());
  },
  onPageError: (page, error) {
    print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
  },
  onViewCreated: (PDFViewController pdfViewController) {
    _controller.complete(pdfViewController);
  },
  onPageChanged: (int page, int total) {
    print('page change: $page/$total');
  },
),
```

package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview).

for list,

```
       ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: length, //pass the length of list
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                        //code for opening pdf goes here
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 4, vertical: 8),
                                      child: Row(children:[
                                        //code of circle avatar
                                       Text("//name of pdf at this index")])
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
```

link of tutorial for [listview.builder](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/listview-builder-in-flutter/)

Comment: this is to view the pdf but before that I want to display the list of pdf that I am getting.

Comment: you can use listview.builder for that, and in that you will make a container with gesture detector and a Text widget to display name (which you can get from path).

Comment: yes i did that but you can see I am not able to display pdf in list.

Comment: can you please upload minimal reproduceable code because i am not getting what exactly with you are facing problem with.

Comment: i did that @Ruchit

Comment: check i updated ans